# tf::TransformListener Time Lookup and Transform Frame Error

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, tf2, transform-listener

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I have been tyring to meddle with `tf::TransformListiner` and see how it works. but every time I try to run my example, I get :

```
Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 2873.875000000 but the latest data is at time 2873.867000000, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [base_footprint]
```

I tried to set the `"/amcl/transform_tolerance"` to some other values (ranging from 1/10 seconds to 0.01) to no avail.
This seems to have been caused by running both gazebo turtlebot3 simulation alongside rviz2 on my system (in a vmware workstation) and seems its struggling because my CPU cant handle such load and thus it introduced a small latency and messed up everything.

apart from using a more powerful PC which at the moment is not possible, what should I do ?
I have read about FilterMessages`, but honestly don't know which one to use and how, since I'm not directly dealing with topics here.

note :
I'm using C++ by the way in case it matters.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you all very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381678/tf::transformlistener-results-in-lookup-would-require-extrapolation-into-the-future.--requested-time-%27x%27-but-the-latest-data-is-at-time-%27y%27,-when-looking-up-transform-from-frame-%5Bodom%5D-to-frame-%5Bbase_footprint%5D/) by [Rika](https://answers.ros.org/users/75014/rika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2021-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-03**:
What do you mean by "rviz2"?

**Comment by [Rika](https://answers.ros.org/users/75014/rika/) on 2021-07-03**:
That's a typo, my RViz version was 1.12.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to [Photon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28317/photon/), after consulting the official documentation ([Learning about tf and time (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20%28C%2B%2B%29)) I found where my problem was.

First of all I had a (wrong) preconception that `Time(0)` and `Time::now()` refer to the very same thing and are interchangeable. I couldn't have been more wrong about this. They are not the same.
The `Time(0)` means `"the latest available transform in the buffer"` while `Time::now()`, literally fetches the frame at the exact moment, and since there is a delay between this command being issued and the frame being fetched, we will have some latencies in milliseconds and this will cause the lookup failure if its not accounted for.
Why is that?(based on tf2 [docs](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/tf2%20and%20time%20%28C%2B%2B%29) which I believe also applies to tf) :

> Each listener has a buffer where it
> stores all the coordinate transforms
> coming from the different tf
> broadcasters. When a broadcaster sends
> out a transform, it takes some time
> before that transform gets into the
> buffer (usually a couple of
> milliseconds). So, when you request a
> frame transform at time "now", you
> should wait a few milliseconds for
> that information to arrive.

In order to fix this I either had to use `Time(0)` and get the **latest available transform in the queue** or if I wanted the frame at roughly now, I had to use  `waitForTransform()`

So to cut a long story short, I either had to do :

```
 transform_listener.lookupTransform("base_footprint", "odom",ros::Time(0), transform);
```

or:

```
ros::Time now = ros::Time::now();
transform_listener.waitForTransform("base_footprint", 
                                    "odom", 
                                     now, 
                                     // the wait duration in seconds
                                     ros::Duration(2));
//note that we used 'now' here as well. if we don't, we will still face lookup error
//as if nothing has changed
transform_listener.lookupTransform("base_footprint", "odom", now, transform);
```

---

Originally posted by [Rika](https://answers.ros.org/users/75014/rika/) with karma: 72 on 2021-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way is to go through the tf tutorial separately without using Gazebo: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials (It's pretty hard to get a decent performance of Gazebo running in a virtual machine, and the extrapolation issue is probably caused by this latency.)

---

Originally posted by [photon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28317/photon/) with karma: 68 on 2021-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rika](https://answers.ros.org/users/75014/rika/) on 2021-07-03**:
Thanks, but I want to fix it rather than leaving it alone as I believe this can happen in real life as well. I want to know why setting `transform_tolerence` didn`t work, or what other options I have aside not using gazebo.